# Get values from 2 spinners and display listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner

The scenario is - user selects the semester(sem1,sem2...etc) value from dropdown and its branch(cs,it...) from another and on the basis of the two selected value a listview contains subjects of the specified semester and branch get populated and on the basis of that subject i want to display the syllabus of that subject..

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.syllabus);
        String[] semarray = new String[] { "Sem 1", "Sem 2", "Sem 3" };
        String[] brancharray = new String[] { "CS", "EC", "EE" };
        semester = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sems);
        branch = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.branch);
        semarrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, semarray);
        semester.setAdapter(semarrayAdapter);
        brancharrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, brancharray);
        branch.setAdapter(brancharrayAdapter);


        semester.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                item1 = semester.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        branch.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                item2 = branch.getSelectedItem().toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        if(item1 == "Sem 1" && item2 == "CS"){
            Toast.makeText(this, "hi me hu",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        };


    }
```

How to implement??? Kindly help

I am pretty new to android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.syllabus);

    String[] semarray = new String[] { "Sem 1", "Sem 2", "Sem 3" };
    String[] brancharray = new String[] { "CS", "EC", "EE" };

    semester = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sems);
    branch = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.branch);        
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    semarrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, semarray);

    semester.setAdapter(semarrayAdapter);

    brancharrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, brancharray);

    branch.setAdapter(brancharrayAdapter);


    semester.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            item1 = semester.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if(item1 != null && item2 != null){

                String[] listArray = new String[]{item1 + " " + item2};

                listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listArray);

                listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

    branch.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {

            item2 = branch.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if(item1 != null && item2 != null){

                String[] listArray = new String[]{item1 + " " + item2};

                listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listArray);

                listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

    if(item1 == "Sem 1" && item2 == "CS"){
        Toast.makeText(this, "hi me hu",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    };


}
```

Comment: thanks...it is working i will implement now as per my requirement